# How to update a nested item in AWS DynamoDB with CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, command-line-interface, aws-cli

In one of my AWS DynamoDB tables I have several items that require an update within in a pipeline.
The following json shows an item in the AWS DynamoDB table:

```json
{
  "DeploymentConfigs": {
    "L": [
      {
        "M": {
          "Config": {
            "M": {
              "Name": {
                "S": "batch-komo"
              },
              "Replicas": {
                "N": "3"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "M": {
          "Config": {
            "M": {
              "Name": {
                "S": "online-komo"
              },
              "Replicas": {
                "N": "3"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "environment": {
    "S": "komo-claimcenter"
  }
}
```

How can update an object in `DeploymentConfigs`?
Primary partition key is `environment`.

E.g. the object

```json
{
        "M": {
          "Config": {
            "M": {
              "Name": {
                "S": "batch-komo"
              },
              "Replicas": {
                "N": "3"
              }
            }
          }
        }
}
```

shall be updated to

```json
   {
        "M": {
          "Config": {
            "M": {
              "Name": {
                "S": "batch-komo"
              },
              "Replicas": {
                "N": "5"
              }
            }
          }
        }
 }
```

I do not know to achieve in the AWS CLI.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update a nested part inside an item, you use an `UpdateExpression` with an attribute path. For example, `SET DeploymentConfigs[0].Config.Replicas = :val`.

The problem, however, is that your top-level attribute `DeploymentConfigs` is a list, so to modify one of its items, you need to know in index (in this example 0). If you don't know the index you have a problem - there is no way to "modify the list item which has name='batch-komo'" or something like that... If you need to do something like this, you have to read the entire top-level attribute, modify it in the client, and write it (or just the small change, now that you know the index) back.